# Pi 4 doesn't recognize .o file format?

Tags: pi-4, c, gcc

Was trying to compile some .c files along with one .o file using gcc, and it failed with an error message saying: .o file format not recognized.

The same files got compiled on centOS vm though.

Comment: You don't "compile" an object file  - it is already compiled. If you have a valid Question you need to provide more detail.

Comment: If your object file is from another architecture (like X86 or X86_64) then that will never work on a Raspberry (ARM architecture) no matter how you try to "compile" or (more correctly) link it with gcc, gpp or g++.

Answer (score 2):

The `.o` files are object files and they must be compiled for the Pi. You cannot take a `.o` file from an X86 platform and expect it to link on a Pi. That produces the error message that you describe, so I assume that is what you did.

`gcc` is also a front-end for the linker, so if your object files are correct, they will be linked by `gcc`.

As an oversimplified example, create the following two files:

`f1.c`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

extern int doit();

int main(){
        doit();
}
```

and `f2.c`:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int doit(){
        printf ("Hello, world\n");
}
```

Create an object-file `f2.o` with `gcc -c f2.c`. You should now have an object file `f2.o`. Next, create the program with `gcc -o hoppa f1.c f2.o`.

And finally:

```
./hoppa
Hello, world
```